# Create a comma separated list of quoted values

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I need to create a list of country names within quotes and a comma at the end - except the last country name, like this: 
(I'm using ColdFusion 10)

```
  "Tuvalu",
  "Uganda",
  "Ukraine",
  "United Arab Emirates",
  "United Kingdom",
  "Uruguay"

  <cfquery name="query_names" datasource="MyDB">
   select short_desc
   from tbl_country
   where NVL(short_desc,' ') <> ' '
   order by short_desc
  </cfquery>
  <cfset TotalRec = "#query_names.Recordcount#">

  <cfloop query="query_names">
     <cfif query_names.Recordcount GT 271>
       <cfoutput>
         "#Trim(short_desc)#" & ","
       </cfoutput>
     <cfelse>
       <cfoutput>
         "#Trim(short_desc)#"
       </cfoutput>
     </cfif>
  </cfloop>
```

This loop result in country names within quotes, but no comma. So my loop result in:

```
  "Tuvalu"
  "Uganda"
  "Ukraine"
  "United Arab Emirates"
  "United Kingdom"
  "Uruguay"
```

Answer (score 9):

If you really need double quotes, it is probably simpler to append the quoted values to an array and convert it to a list at the end. The  [ArrayToList](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/arraytolist.html) function automatically handles the commas for you:

```
<cfset names = []>
<cfloop query="query_names">
    <cfset arrayAppend(names, '"'& short_desc & '"')>
</cfloop>

<cfoutput>#arrayToList(names)#</cfoutput>
```

**Result:**

```
"Tuvalu","Uganda","Ukraine","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","Uruguay"
```

Side note, if single quotes, i.e., `'` are acceptable, it is even simpler. Skip the looping and just use [QuotedValueList()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/quotedvaluelist.html):

```
 <cfoutput>#quotedValueList(query_names.short_desc)#</cfoutput>
```

**Result:**

```
'Tuvalu','Uganda','Ukraine','United Arab Emirates','United Kingdom','Uruguay'
```

Comment: Nice! I like your answer better!

Comment: (Edit fix silly typos) @CodyCaughlan - Thanks :) It would be great if QuotedValueList allowed specifying the type of quote, but ... cest la vie.

Comment: c'est la Adobe  :P

Comment: @Alex - Lol, I am keeping that one.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions. The one that is working the best is using the array. Other, especially using cfloop like my original codes, work slower esp when I have a large recordcount

Comment: @ale - Thanks for the corrections! I missed those two.

Answer (score 2):

I hope **listQualify()** does the same in pretty easier way. isn't it???

```
<cfset myQry = queryNew("country","varchar",[["Tuvalu"],["Uganda"],["Ukraine"],["United Arab Emirates"],["United Kingdom"],["Uruguay"]])>
<cfdump var="#listQualify(valueList(myQry.country),'"')#" />
```

Also we can use **quotedValueList()** as **Leigh** mentioned, if we need single quoted list.

Comment: (Mentioned this in the comments of a now deleted answer). Yes, I thought about a similar approach but decided against it because the results get all skewed when the query values contain commas.

Answer (score 1):

User1557856, you were so close. Your answer is actually good, but for one point. If you correct it, you will get what you want.

The reason why you obtained a list without commas is this:

```
<cfif query_names.Recordcount GT 271>
```

This condition is always false apparently. So only the `<cfelse></cfif>` part of the code is run. That is the part without commas, hence the result.

If you modify your code slightly, as follows, you will get the desired result:

```
<cfloop query="query_names">
     <cfif query_names.currentRow LT query_names.Recordcount>
       <cfoutput>
         "#Trim(short_desc)#",
       </cfoutput>
     <cfelse>
       <cfoutput>
         "#Trim(short_desc)#"
       </cfoutput>
     </cfif>
 </cfloop>
```